# knockoutjs highcharts parse arrays of data to chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, highcharts

I am using a combination of highcharts and knockoutjs to feed data into my chart.

I have 4 massive arrays of data that need to be fed into my highchart upon a click event. I showed the data arrays empty here due to their huge size.  Currently it returns an error like: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metric' of undefined**

My question is how do I access the areas.metric.data and parse it into my chart?

here is my (non) working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/BG8Qe/18/

```
function MetricsViewModel(areas) {
    var self = this;
    self.areas = [ // data structure
        {
            name: 'Game',
            metrics: [{name : 'metric1', id : 'usdeur', data : []}, {name : 'metric2', id : 'msft', data : []}]
        },    
        {
            name: 'Player',
            metrics: [{name : 'metric1', id : 'msft', data : []}, {name : 'metric2', id : 'msft', data : []}]
        },
        {
            name: 'Social',
            metrics: [{name : 'metric1', id : 'googl', data : [] }, {name : 'metric2', id : 'msft', data : []}]
        }        
    ];


    series: [{ // default series
        id: 'adbe',
        data: ADBE
    }]
    }, function(chart){
        var data = areas.metric.data; // corresponds to my object above ^^^

    self.updateChart = function(metric) {
        var id = this.id,
            series = chart.get(id);
        if(!series){
            chart.addSeries({
                id: id,
                data: data
            });  
        } else {          
            series.remove();
        }                
        console.log(metric);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here's a fork of your fiddle based on @Madman's answer. http://jsfiddle.net/nphyK/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but according your code, this function declared in the ViewModel scope:

```
function(chart){
```

so you can access access both areas array and you observable metrics array like this:

**var data = self.areas[0].metrics;**

or observable metrics array like

**self.metrics()**

in any case, at the line where you have troubles, you are in ViewModel scope and can access whatever you want in it by **this** or **self**